# How to make ekf localization node for multiple ridgeback robots

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, husky, ekf-localization, multi-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, Now I'm running with Ubuntu 16.04, ROS kinetic (ROS1)
I also working with my Gazebo multi ridgeback robots by modifying the [ridgeback_simulation](https://www.clearpathrobotics.com/assets/guides/ridgeback/simulation.html)
But the problem is I don't know how to let EKF localization node works for multiple robots.  The similar question has mentioned here since 2016 [similar_q](https://answers.ros.org/question/226274/is-it-possible-to-use-robot_localization-for-multiple-robots/). From my understanding, to make multiple EKF localization node we have to edit frameID from gazebo xacro file and put name space, tf_prefix for them.  But finally, I still cannot do it with my ridgeback. The problem is it show that

```
Could not obtain transform from robot_1/base_link to /base_link. Error was "robot_1/base_link" passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame does not exist
```

Finally, I have found that someone can do it with multiple Husky robots simulation.[multi_husky_explanation](https://clearpathrobotics.com/blog/2016/03/simulating-multiple-husky-ugvs-in-gazebo/) and the git repo here [multi_husky_git_repo](https://github.com/bsb808/nre_simmultihusky). So, I have downloaded the original Husky package and try to run the multihusky launch file. And found that

1. The kinect URDF file locazation was changed. So I have edit the mhusky.gazebo.xacro
   only one line as following
   `<xacro:include filename="$(find husky_description)/urdf/accessories/kinect_camera.urdf.xacro"/>`
2. When I launch the multihusky.launch. I have found the error below
   `re/src/nre_simmultihusky/xacro/mhusky.gazebo.xacro'         laser_enabled:=true ur5_enabled:=false         kinect_enabled:=false         nsp:=h1 tfpre:=h1_tf         ] returned with code [2]. Param xml is <param command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py --inorder '$(find nre_simmu ltihusky)/xacro/mhusky.gazebo.xacro'         laser_enabled:=$(arg laser_enabled )         ur5_enabled:=$(arg ur5_enabled)         kinect_enabled:=$(arg kinect_ enabled)         nsp:=$(arg namespace)         tfpre:=$(arg tfpre)         " na me="robot_description"/> The traceback for the exception was written to the log file`

According to the multihusky repo, they give TF tree shown that multiple EKF nodes can work properly here [nre_simmultihusky wiki](https://github.com/bsb808/nre_simmultihusky/wiki). So my question is how I can run this file to understand how they create multiple EKF localization node. Please help me!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329237/how-to-make-ekf-localization-node-for-multiple-ridgeback-robots/) by [Soloist](https://answers.ros.org/users/44246/soloist/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2019-07-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I ran into this same issue while also enabling multi robot simulation for ridgeback.

I had the correct tf prefixes for ekf_localization however I was still seeing the same /base_link error caused by the missing namespace/tf prefix.

I was able to fix this by modifying the velocity controller's `base_frame_id` and `odom_frame_id`.

```
<rosparam param="ridgeback_velocity_controller/base_frame_id" subst_value="True">$(arg tfpre)/base_link</rosparam>
<rosparam param="ridgeback_velocity_controller/odom_frame_id" subst_value="True">$(arg tfpre)/odom</rosparam>
```

In addition to the [nre_simmultihusky repo](https://github.com/bsb808/nre_simmultihusky), there is [shehancaldera's more recent multi husky repo](https://github.com/shehancaldera/multihusky_simulator). I found both useful for figuring out the tf tree for ridgeback.

The top portion of my tf tree looks like this:

- map
- r0_tf/odom

  - r0_tf/base_link

    - r0_tf/chassis_link
    - r0_tf/mid_mount
- r1_tf/odom

  - r1_tf/base_link

    - r1_tf/chassis_link
    - r1_tf/mid_mount

Each translation is handled by the following broadcaster:

```
+-----------------+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
| Parent          | Child              | Broadcaster                                          |
+-----------------+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
| map             | r0_tf/odom         | r0/map_odom_broadcaster (static_transform_publisher) |
+-----------------+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
| r0_tf/odom      | r0_tf/base_link    | r0/ekf_localization                                  |
+-----------------+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
| r0_tf/base_link | r0_tf/chassis_link | r0/robot_state_publisher                             |
+-----------------+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

Originally posted by [liorlustgarten](https://answers.ros.org/users/58850/liorlustgarten/) with karma: 16 on 2020-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0